# Efficiently find the n-ring of every node in a graph in python

Tags: python, numpy, graph

I have a numpy array of M edge definitions that is Mx2 and contains node indexes. For every node, I would like to find edges inside the n-ring (in my case 3-ring) of the node. I have N=250K nodes from a medium dense computational mesh for a numercial model, so I'm looking for something appropriately efficient and sparse.

Comment: What do you mean by "n-ring"?

Comment: nodes that are separated by one edge from the one under consideration are in the 1-ring, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
G = nx.dorogovtsev_goltsev_mendes_graph(4)
edges_list = G.edges()
edges_list = np.array(edges_list)
one_ring = []
for n in G.nodes():
    first = edges_list[edges_list[:, 0] == n, 1]
    second = edges_list[edges_list[:, 1] == n, 0]
    one_ring.append(np.hstack([first, second]))
N = 3
n_ring = []
def find_n_ring(root, node, i):
    if i >= N:
        return node
    for node2 in one_ring[node]:
        n_ring_node = find_n_ring(root, node2, i + 1)
        if n_ring_node is not None and n_ring_node not in n_ring[root]:
            n_ring[root].append(n_ring_node)
for root in G.nodes():
    n_ring.append([])
    find_n_ring(root, root, 0)
print(n_ring)
```